# Add Tax to shipping cost on opencart(2.0.3.1) order email (client and admin)

Tags: php, arrays, opencart, opencart2.x

[image]

I would like to add the **handling fee** if the text ***handling fee*** exist to the order's shipping weight cost. I would also like to avoid editing any controller. How can I do this with just editing the `confirm.tpl` from my view?

```
<tfoot>
      <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</strong></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
</tfoot>
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
<tfoot>
      <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>

      <?php 
        if(strpos($total['title'], "Handling") !== false) {
          // handling exists, what now?
        }
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</strong></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$totals = array(
    array('title' => 'Handling Fee', 'text' => '₱171.33'),
    array('title' => 'Sub-Total', 'text' => '₱17,132.85'),
    array('title' => 'Nationwide Fee', 'text' => '₱280.00')
);


?>


<tfoot>
    <?php $toAdd = 0; foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
    <?php 
    if(strpos($total['title'], "Handling") !== false) { 
        $toAdd = (float)preg_replace('/[^.a-zA-Z0-9]/s', '', $total['text']);
    } else { ?> 
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</strong></td>
            <td class="text-right"><?php 
                if($toAdd && (strpos($total['title'], 'Nationwide') !== false)) {
                    $nationwide = (float)preg_replace('/[^.a-zA-Z0-9]/s', '', $total['text']);
                    echo "₱". number_format($nationwide + $toAdd, 2, '.', ','); 
                } else {
                    echo $total['text']; 
                }
            ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</tfoot>
```

Here is one dry and dirty answer. If I can improve this, please let me now. It uses strpos to hide the handling fee and preg_replace casted as float in order for me to perform some basic arithmetic operations.